# External Evaluate Conversion method

Tags: python, external-calls

One can run a command for example in python using `ExternalEvaluate`

```
ExternalEvaluate["Python", <|"Command" -> "max", 
  "Arguments" -> {1, 2, 3, 4}|>]
```

The syntax that is used here is poorly documented and has to be inferred from the examples in the documentation. It is not clear for example whether the association could contain other entries than "Command" and "Arguments" and if so what would be done with it. Anyway, is there a way to combine this syntax with the option `"ReturnType"->"String"`. The following does not work:

```
ExternalEvaluate["Python",<|"Command"->"max","Arguments"->{1,2,3,4}, "ReturnType"->"String"|>]
```

---

The following syntax works

```
ExternalEvaluate["Python"->"String",<|"Command"->"max","Arguments"->{1,2,3,4}|>]
```

but I should clarify that I want to run a specific python environment and the same does not work with that (even though the conversion of the arguments etc does work correctly). So I am really looking for a solution of the form:

```
ExternalEvaluate[pyth->"String",<|"Command"->"max","Arguments"->{1,2,3,4}"|>]
```

where `pyth=ExternalSessionObject[...]`, which unfortunately does not evaluate.

---

Also is it known what conversion Mathematica uses here on for example `{1,2,3,4}`. Is it possible to act with the same conversion on a general expression (returning the result as a string)?

Comment: This works for me under Linux:  `pyth = StartExternalSession[<|"System" -> "Python",
    "ReturnType" -> "String"|>];
ExternalEvaluate[pyth, <|"Command" -> "max", 
  "Arguments" -> {1, 2, 3, 4}|>]`.

Comment: @LouisB, thanks! That works. It is not ideal though since it requires me to create two external sessions. One for `Expression` output and one for `String` output. I guess it is the closest thing.

Comment: Maybe you could apply `ToExpression` to the string, or even `ToString` to the expression, if that helps.

Comment: @LouisB, the conversion does more than apply `ToExpression` I believe. In fact if I would really know what it does and if it is a one-to-one map (with its inverse available to) than of course that would solve the issue. For example python lists and dictionaries get mapped to Mathematica lists and Associations. This is non-trivial. The same applies to `ToString` it would give me the string version of the Mathematica output but not the string version of the python output that I want to retrieve in this case.